# Copy Excel sheets as picture and order each image underneath the last one

Tags: excel, vba

I've changed my code a bit; I found that copying each sheet as a picture keeps the tables in their original format much better then copy and pasting with `PasteSpecial xl PasteAll/xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`. Right now, all the pictures are pasting one top of one another, and I'm looking to have each picture underneath each or some beside each other. this is what i have so far:

```
For fileIdx = 1 To fileSlct.SelectedItems.Count         'Loops through each of the selected items so we can use the sheets in the book
    Set srcBook = Workbooks.Open((fileSlct.SelectedItems(fileIdx)), ReadOnly:=True)
    Set xlSheet = srcBook.ActiveSheet
    For Each xlSheet In srcBook.Sheets
    Set rng = xlSheet.UsedRange       '"Selects" the data to be copied
    xlSheet.Activate
    With xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
        .UnMerge                                    'Sence there are a lot of merged cells, we need to unmerge
        rng.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture     'Copies the range as diffined above
        .PasteSpecial
    End With
    Next xlSheet
    srcBook.Close False
Next fileIdx
```

Edit add: Will I need the part with merged cells, if the tables are being copied as pictures?

Comment: You can use the `Top` and `Left` properties of the shape class to position images: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape

Comment: I'm a newbie to VBA, and not really sure how to do it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Top` property of the [`Shape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape) class to position the copies. The `Sheet` class has a `Shapes` collection which we can use to reference which shape to position:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
   .UnMerge
   rng.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
   .PasteSpecial
End With

If ws.Shapes.Count = 1 Then ' position at top
   ws.Shapes(1).Top = 0
Else
   ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count).Top = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count - 1).Height + 5 ' or whatever gap you want
End If
```

Comment: At `ws.shapes.(0).top = 0` I'm getting an Run-time error with a bunch of long numbers, the index into the specified collection is out of bounds

Comment: My bad, that collection is 1 bound, not 0 i.e. the index goes from 1 for the first shape, 2 for the second etc. As a rule of thumb collections of objects like sheets or shapes go from 1, collections of data like a string array go from 0. I've updated the post. Check out the shapes collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes